Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API returns status code 400 and only provides requestId and totalBilledTime
I am trying to use the Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API to convert audio data to text. However, I keep getting a status code 400 error when I send the request. Additionally, the conversion result only contains requestId and totalBilledTime, but no text. I would appreciate any advice on how to fix this issue.
Here is the relevant portion of my code:
import axios from 'axios';
import { REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLOUD_TEXT_TO_SPEECH_API_KEY, REALTIME_DATABASE, PROJECT_ID } from "@env";

async function SpeechToText({ base64 }) {
  let data = {
    "config": {
      "encoding": "LINEAR16",
      "sampleRateHertz": 16000,
      "languageCode": "ja-JP",
    },
    "audio": {
      "content": base64,
    },
  };

  try {
    console.log(base64, "base64");
    console.log("Converting voice chat to text...");
    const response = await axios.post(
      `https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognizekey=${REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLOUD_TEXT_TO_SPEECH_API_KEY}`,
      data
    );
    console.log("Conversion result:", response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to convert speech to text:", error);
  }
}

I have:

Verified that the API key is correct.
Ensured that the request data format is correct.
Added detailed logging for the error message.

What could be causing this error and how can I fix it?
Additional Information:

The audio data is Base64 encoded.
The Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API is enabled.
Billing is set up correctly.


The method is recognize and key is a query parameter (i.e. recognize?key=${REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLOUD_TEXT_TO_SPEECH_API_KEY}

Thank you for your comment!
Indeed, as you pointed out, there was a missing ?. I added it, but the issue persists. Even when outputting response.data to the console, I only get requestId and totalBilledTime. What's even more strange is that the totalBilledTime is longer than the recorded time.
Do you have any idea what might be happening?

It's difficult to help because your issue is not reproducible (no base64 content etc.). It's possible that you need to specify Accept and Content-Type headers valued application/json to axios.post
